Pandas read_excel is throwing an issue related to datetime conversion while reading an .xlsx or .xls file, but file doesn’t have any datetime columns
By using below code facing  issue:
I am trying to read .xslx as well .xls file.
df = pd.read_excel(filepath,sheet_name = "Package ID Informatio", header=hd, dtype=str)

Code is running well in python3.7 version but facing issue while runing this in 3.12 version.
File "C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 61, in _convert
    raise TypeError('expected ' + str(expected_type))
TypeError: expected <class 'datetime.datetime'>


please share version of pandas you're using - it's pretty relevant for this problem. (import pandas as pd; pd.__version__)

also, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example showing any / all inputs/errors

pandas   version  I am using is  2.2.3

Please help me to read the file .xls

We can't guess what's wrong with an unknown Excel file. Are you sure you aren't trying to read from the wrong row ? If you want to skip rows use skiprows, not header. If you want to prevent parsing use dtype=object. The Python version doesn't affect how openpyxl works and Python 3.7 is very old anyway. It's quite likely the Excel file starts with date-like values in a column and continues with non-date values
